# Can high-rep users see deleted comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments, moderator-abilities

Can high-rep users see deleted comments?

If so, at what reputation level?

Otherwise,

- Should it be possible?
- Would it be useful?
- Where do comments go when they die - do comments get removed from the database or just hidden?

Comment: Only moderators (and by extension Stack Exchange employees with developer/moderator access) can see deleted comments. So, this is really a discussion about your **else**.

Comment: Ah didn't think about the ♦ possibility!

Comment: [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/60098/my-most-upvoted-comments-including-comment-text) can show you deleted comments also.

Comment: Meta let us see our deleted comments: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187279/let-us-view-our-deleted-comments

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, only moderators (on their respective sites only), community managers and the SE developers can see deleted comments.

I don't see any reason why that should be possible as comments shouldn't have much value in them.

By default everything on the site is soft-deleted so moderators can see the history on posts, including comment threads.

It's in very rare cases, for example when username/password or other private data is in a post, that a developer purges a record from the database.

Comment: Moderators hard-delete posts whenever they contain personal information.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi No, that is not correct. Moderators can't do that. Only developers can, hence my distinction in those three groups: mods, CM's and dev's.

Comment: That was a typo on my end. I meant to say "developers", not "moderators".

Comment: Moderators also delete posts that call them out when they mess up (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613499/865175).

Comment: @IulianOnofrei what is the point of your comment, except for rehashing a mistake made by a human being two years ago?

Comment: The point is that StackOverflow is getting worse and worse. Here's another example, a perfect answer, with a delete vote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457280/865175. Why?!

Comment: @IulianOnofrei  because your first revision was awful https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20932931 and so the votes were for that revision: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52457280/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries it shows to me that SO works perfectly because you edited and improved the answer after that. Delete votes don't expire but due to its score we can no longer delete vote it.

Comment: I'm shocked. This is countering every effort from everyone engaging in data privacy. If SE calls it "delete" but in fact its just "hide", it's fake, it's a moral fraud.

Comment: @DanielW. I'm shocked you're shocked. 26 or so elected moderators that are held to a moderator agreement and SE staff have access to deleted comments so they can properly do their moderation duties. Don't you think calling it "fake" and "moral fraud" is a tiny bit over the top? What do you call Facebook then? You must be lost for words.

Comment: @rene fair points. I am unsure about the specific words (in english). When I hit the "delete" link, but it doesn't delete the comment from the servers it's saved to, then my understanding of "delete" is maybe a translation problem. "delete" from my understanding is: all digital or analog copies are removed from the other party's posession. I try to avoid companies that keep my data after I deleted it or make it difficult in requesting the removal of data via GDPR. It's a flaw in data privacy regulations which will be countered in the next 10 years.

Comment: @DanielW. you, and others, are mixing up Personal Data and your contributions. Your Personal Data is governed by the [privacy policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy). Your contributions (posts, comments) are governed by the [irrevocable content license](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) you granted SE when you signed up. IMO SE has one of the better privacy policies and governing across the net. I would rather trust my online identity here then anywhere else. If it really bothers you see https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr for options

Answer (score 25):

> Should it be possible?

No, it shouldn't. Comments are and have always been secondary to the actual posts - questions and answers. Giving them more visibility goes against that.

> Would it be useful?

Possibly, for an extremely minor number of cases. Not really worth it, IMO.

> Where do comments go when they die - do comments get removed from the database or just hidden?

They are hidden (aka soft deleted). This is needed in cases where moderators require the history of the post - conflict resolution and to see why a post was flagged, for example.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that moderators have operated under the assumption that deleted comments would never be visible to normal users at any privilege level ever again. There have been many horrible, horrible things that have been written in comments which we merely deleted, and didn't have manually purged from the database, because we thought no one would ever see them again. If these comments were made visible to normal users, that could cause a problem, and we wouldn't be able to go back and revisit these problematic comments for formal removal from the database.

Comment: I've got to confess to a certain morbid curiosity about the textual atrocities committed by a supposedly intelligent group of people (or by a subset of that group, at least).

Comment: @Oded, I believe that moderators can't see comment edits. Is a SE developer able to see comment edits looking in the database or a server log? I'm thinking that an abusive user could say bad words and edit it to hide an offense instead of deleting the comment.

Comment: @Zanon - moderators and developers can see deleted comments. As for edited comments - those are indicated on the comment itself (depends on the site, but normally a small pencil icon) - only the last version is retained, so yes, it is possible that in the 5 minutes allowed for a comment edit, it would be changed.

Comment: More interestingly, why can't OP see their own comments that were deleted by mods - or by whom and why they were deleted? Seems somebody had implemented "secret police" functionality. Cue "the road to hell is paved with good intentions"

Comment: I don't know about "Secret police" but it is frustrating that I'm 99% positive I had an innocuous comment deleted but I can't be sure and I'll never know why.  Did I do something wrong? Did it never post in the first place? Did I dream it? I'll never know!

Comment: @THEJOATMON The worst thing for me is that I'll find a clarification related to an answer, post that info so it helps everyone (including myself), come back later when I need to find it, and *poof*, it's gone. It's encouraging me to make answers that are [existing answer] plus some small, comment-worthy addition. At least then I have a record. That, to be clear, is bad. Comments are useful, and if they're soft-deleted, why not let me see at least my own? (Iirc, I've come back to a comment that had over 50 upvotes once and it was gone, no changes to question to integrate it. /sigh)

Answer (score -3):

- Should it be possible?

  Yes!
- Would it be useful?

  Yes, it would let people uncover moderation abuse. As it is, people who have the power to delete comments can do so with impunity.

I recently left a useful comment under a useful answer. The answer was good, but in the last sentence it claimed something was impossible. I left a comment stating it was possible, explained how, and left 2 links that would be useful to someone reading the question and answer. In other words, the links would help someone reading this actually come to a useful solution.

When I checked the next day, the sentence in the answer about something being impossible was removed but so was my comment, including the useful links. IMO whoever deleted the comment abused their privilege.

I have no way to prove this though because I can't point to the deletion of the comment.

Comment: If you have something that needs to be preserved for posterity, it shouldn't be in a comment.  That's not what comments are for.  If the information is that important, it should be in either the answer you are commenting on, or in / as a separate answer.

Comment: Comments for things that are not answers. It is perfectly normal to leave a useful link in a comment. It's not only normal, it's encouraged. Leaving it as an answer gets it flagged as "not an answer"

Comment: Useful comments are the number. [Here's the #1 votes c++ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array). First comment is a useful link. 5th comment on top answer is a useful link. Links on comments also add to the "linked" side bar. If comments weren't for useful info there'd be no reason for the "linked" side bar to reference them.

Comment: Fine.  But people should not be surprised if their comments are deleted.  Like I said, this is not how the designers intended them to be used.  And as Brad Larson's comments on another answer explain, making deleted comments visible has serious (IMO, show stopper)  negative consequences.

Comment: The designers fully intended them to be useful otherwise they wouldn't be referencing them the linked side bar. Your claim is nonsense. We can also go through the existing comments and see how they are full of useful info. The site would be significantly less useful without the info in the comments.

Comment: *"IMO whoever deleted the comment abused their privilege."* - IMO, whoever deleted the comment was within their rights to do it.  If you have a beef with people deleting comments, that is a separate topic to this one.

Comment: No.  The point is that the designers intended comments to be *ephemeral*.  Lifetime and usefulness are *different issues*.  This is why questions can be flagged as "No longer needed".

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/35831.  Anyway, if you have specific evidence that a comment deletion was arbitrary (or a mistake), that should be raised with the moderators.

Comment: Don't accuse people of "making things up".  It is insulting.

Comment: There is zero proof comments were meant to be ephemeral. As more yet evidence, if they were meant to ephemeral there would be no voting system on comments. What's the point in having a comment with 100-200+ votes if the point is to delete them. It is not separate topic from this one. Deleted comments should be just as visible as deleted answers or at least visible to the commenter

Comment: @StephenC "_Anyway, if you have specific evidence that a comment deletion was arbitrary (or a mistake)_" How would you even know? You don't get alerts that they're deleted, and you can't even see your own deleted comments when you revisit a question. You should _at least_ be able to see your own deleted comments (and receive a notification) if only to be able to raise these issues, as you suggest.