# Is there any way to report a user if a rude comment is deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I had a pretty rough discussion and received a rude comment which has been deleted immediately.

So, I have two questions:

1. How can I report a user for an offensive answer/comment if it is deleted? From the profile? Any moderators chat?
2. The whole thread was born from a total misunderstanding after the first comment was edited, so, maybe a better way to prevent such a situations would be an ability to see comments edit history, like in answers?

Comment: If it was deleted, chances are a moderator took care of it real quick, or the author realized immediately it was wrong. I wouldn't worry about it as long as it's off the site. As for comment edit history, I don't think that's even stored, since comments are second class citizens and all.

Comment: Comments are second-class citizens and are subject to deletion at any time.  So there's not too much you can do.  Since the comment is already deleted, the moderators' typical action of removing the offending content is already taken care of.  If it's _really_ bad, you could use a custom moderator attention flag on one of the user's posts (explain everything, mention the deleted comments), but I don't think that most situations will warrant this action.

Comment: Is there any _need_ to report a user if rude comment is deleted? The comment is deleted. It can't hurt anybody any more.

Comment: Except for me, the one, for whom comment was posted. It was rude and were addressed to me personally.

Comment: @Sega-Zero Yeah, but it's gone now. Forget about it, it's just one of billions of people typing a few characters you don't care for and which briefly appeared on a site you don't own for a few moments.  There are other things to worry about!

Comment: I already did:) i was just wondering what can be done in case the comment was very ignominious

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place for emotions. It is a place for answers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Usually, if a rude comment was deleted, it was done so as a result of a moderator acting on a flag. However, [certain particularly abusive words](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835) can trigger an immediate deletion of a comment without a moderator seeing it, or a large enough number of community flags can lead to a deletion.

If you believe someone has been particularly abusive in a comment and that moderators may not have seen it because it was automatically deleted, you can raise a custom flag on the post itself and let us know. We can see deleted comments, and can take further action if needed.

In this case, we were aware of what happened and it's being looked into now.

Comment: In the rare event that a bad comment is self deleted by a user, is that a situation that actually needs to be addressed? Wouldn't we presume the user realized their mistake and deleted it to rectify the situation? Or would moderators want to investigate anyway?

Comment: @Brad, If the comment is self-deleted, does it still exist in the database?

Comment: @jpmc26 - We have seen people leave horribly abusive comments so that people would see them in their inbox, then immediately delete them so that moderators wouldn't catch them. In really abusive cases like that, it might be useful to flag so we can see if more action is needed.

Comment: @Pacerier - Yes. All deleted comments are available to us. Only in extremely rare cases are they purged on the SE side. That lets us examine rudeness that people might be trying to hide from us.

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware that scenario was common. jpmc has a point though: everybody makes mistakes and deletion is surely more often "oops, yeah, that was bad, never mind" than "ha ha now you can only see this in your inbox i'm such a badarse mehehehe". Doesn't feel right to go after people for the former. Can the two even be distinguished?

Comment: That would be an argument for fixing the bug where it's still visible in Inbox after deletion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit did somebody say the scenario was common, and does it matter if it's common or not? When it happens, it needs to be dealt with.

Comment: @BradLarson, are moderators able to see comment edits? I'm asking because an abusive user could say rude words and edit the comment to hide it forever. My hidden bad word: <edited>   :)

Comment: @BradLarson, my bad word was "php". [Oded confirmed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267887/can-high-rep-users-see-deleted-comments/267889?noredirect=1#comment213622_267889) that only the last version is visible for mods.

Comment: @Zanon Nobody likes that foul language here, watch it please, will you?

Comment: @Zanon flagged for vulgar conduct!