# Can I undelete a deleted comment?

Tags: support, comments

I accidentally deleted my own comment. Can I undelete it, similar to how I can undelete a deleted answer?

I know that [moderators can read deleted comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267887/can-high-rep-users-see-deleted-comments). So it should technically be possible to restore a deleted comment.

Of course I could comment again, but having the option to restore the deleted comment feels like a cleaner solution.

Comment: I think it's kind of like [this](http://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/deep-thoughts-lava/n10323?snl=1).

Comment: Why did you delete the comment in the first place?

Comment: @torazaburo Incorrectly thought I included a wrong reference link. Deleted quickly to avoid being beaten by OP.

Comment: It is not possible to redo or undo a moment in time which has passed.

Comment: This should be possible if the comment is of your own! like in questions or answers. It just happened to me :(

Comment: Using SO for Teams, I, as a moderator, accidentally clicked "delete" on a comment. No confirmation, no restoration. Had to ask the user to repost his comment, screwing up the conversation timeline.

Answer (score 37):

There is no way for you to undelete a comment of yours that has been deleted.

Comment: Clear cut answer. So re-posting is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Well technically there is a way. Step 1 become a diamond moderator, Step 2 undelete the comment.

Comment: @MartinSmith except moderators can't undelete self-deleted comments...

Comment: @JonClements Ah, that plan is foiled then!

Comment: @MartinSmith Just replace "become a diamond moderator" with "become an admin/employee of Stack Exchange".

Comment: @Tom I would assume (hope?) only a handful of SE employees actually have DB access, so even then, you'd need to get a specific type of job there.

Comment: @Servy Well, you don't need that access yourself, just ask one of your co-workers who have it :P. Anyway I would also assume that this access is limited and tracked.

Comment: @Tom You don't need to be an SE employee to ask some other SE employee to use their DB access to undelete a comment for you.

Comment: @Servy I don't think that the chances for them to do that are as high as you were a co-worker.

Comment: @Tom I see no reason why internal "restore my comment" request would get any preference... I see why it could be other way around - re-typing even 500 characters should not take longer than work for probably several people to review and approve DB change...

Comment: Change "become a diamond moderator" to "become **two** diamond moderators".  (You are never alone with a clone :-) )