# Can moderator see previous version (before edited) of comments?

Tags: support, comments, moderator-abilities

According to [Can high-rep users see deleted comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267887/can-high-rep-users-see-deleted-comments) only moderators (on their respective sites only), community managers and the SE developers can see deleted comments.

That is about deleted comment.... I am asking that previous version (before edited) of comments?

Comment: Are you asking for a friend?

Comment: @Timothy I'm sure Donkey King is asking for the other Donkey King

Comment: There only used to be one Donkey King. A revolution seems to have split the kingdom.

Comment: @Timothy Actually it is for me :-D

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes. Moderators can see deleted comments *and* revision histories for comments.

If you repeatedly post comments that violate our [Be Nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice/), and then edit out the offensive language within the 5-minute grace period, we will be able to catch you. Think before you post.

That is the only case I can ever imagine where we would look at the revision history for a comment.

Comment: Hmmmm I will think before post.. :-)

Comment: As a follow up, can you see _deleted_ comments? Asking for a friend of course.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ "Yes. Moderators can see deleted comments…"