# Missing/deleted comments

Tags: discussion

I recently noted some of my comments have gone missing or deleted. Is this because they were flagged or is there somebody with reps to delete them without notifying me of their deletion, and if so, what is the privilege to do so?

Comment: You've never had any comments deleted except by yourself. I suspect you've got comments that aren't appearing in your comment activity as they're on a *deleted post*.

Comment: Since activity of deleted comments are not recorded then my history would not indicate that they have been deleted, no..

Comment: What I mean is - you haven't had any *comments* deleted... If you've left comments on a post and that *post* becomes deleted - the comments are still there and viewable by users able to view the post - they just won't show up in your comment history - but if the post were to be undeleted - they then would again.

Comment: Which answers one of my questions, the reps for user, and is 10K..

Comment: There's two separate things here. Only mods or the OP of a comment can delete a comment (it's rare but flags can do so in some cases) - it isn't a reputation level privilege. Users with 10k+ rep will still be able to see comments (where the comment itself isn't deleted) on deleted posts. Only mods can see  comments that have actually been deleted themselves... Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, it isn't a reputation level privilege then! That answers my question!

Answer (score 2):

> Is this because they were flagged

**YES** , if your comment is deleted may be some one has flagged them as

- rude or abusive
- no longer needed
- in need of moderator intervention

> is there somebody with reps to delete them without notifying me of their deletion

**Yes** moderator can delete your comment and and i don't thing it necessary to notify when comment is deleted

> what is the privilege to do so?

Please have look  [Can high-rep users see deleted comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267887/can-high-rep-users-see-deleted-comments)

Please have look [Please notify users when their comment is deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255137/please-notify-users-when-their-comment-is-deleted)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I still think it would be nice to inform a user when a comment has been deleted. Although since they are "secondary nature" i spose not!?

Comment: @eoredson check this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255137/please-notify-users-when-their-comment-is-deleted

Comment: A comment being "second class citizens" sounds arbitrary to me. It should have just a high priority as anything else.

Comment: @eoredson except they're not. Only the OP can edit them and then only within 5 minutes. They can be upvoted but not downvoted and they don't have a public revision history. They're not at all the same as posts.

Comment: Ok, then bump up the priority of comments (just kidding)...

Comment: @eoredson full run down of comments at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Comment: That helps, especially the "Who can delete comments?" part..